# HomkeKit dev: "Enter setup code" page appears only half a second and jump to page "Couldn't add DeviceName, Home couldn't connect to this accessory"

Tags: ios, homekit

I am learning to develop HomeKit App. I was trying to add an accessory to home/room. When I run the project, it's able to discover the accessories but not able to add it to a home or assign a room to the accessory.

According to the tutorial, the project discovers the accessories as below: 
[image]

When I add the accessory to home/room, the "Enter setup code" **appears only for half a second** and then it turns to "Couldn't add XXX, Home couldn't connect this accessory" intermediatly, as shown below:

[image]

[image]
The partial code I used to add accessory to room/home is shown below:

currentRoomVC.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "MyHomeKit.h"
@interface currentRoomVC : UIViewController<UIScrollViewDelegate,UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource,HMAccessoryBrowserDelegate>
@property (nonatomic,strong)HMRoom *currentRoom;
@property (nonatomic,strong)HMRoom *currentHome;

@property(nonatomic,strong) NSMutableArray *accArry;
@property(weak,nonatomic) IBOutlet UIScrollView *scroView;
@property(strong,nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *accTable;

@property(nonatomic,strong) HMAccessoryBrowser *browser;
@end
```

currentRoomVC.m

```
#import "currentRoomVC.h"

@interface currentRoomVC ()

@end

@implementation currentRoomVC
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewWillAppear:YES];
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.hidden = NO;
}
- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewWillDisappear:YES];
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.hidden = YES;
    [self.browser stopSearchingForNewAccessories];
}
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
    self.navigationItem.title = self.currentRoom.name;

    self.accArry = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    self.browser = [[HMAccessoryBrowser alloc]init];
    self.browser.delegate = self;

    [self configSearchBtn];
    [self cofigureTableview];


}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}



#pragma mark -
#pragma mark accessoryBrowser



- (void) configSearchBtn{
    UIButton *addProject = [UIButton buttonWithType: UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    addProject.frame = CGRectMake(self.view.bounds.size.width/2-50, self.view.bounds.size.height / 4-10, 100, 40);
    [addProject setTitle:@"Add device" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [addProject addTarget:self action:@selector(searchDevice:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    addProject.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    [self.view addSubview:addProject];

}

- (void)searchDevice:(UIButton*) button
{
    NSLog(@"Start searching new devices...");
    [self.browser startSearchingForNewAccessories];
}




- (void) accessoryBrowser:(HMAccessoryBrowser *)browser didFindNewAccessory:(HMAccessory *)accessory{
    NSLog(@"Found a new device: %@", accessory.name);
    [_accArry addObject:accessory];
    NSLog(@"%lu", (unsigned long)_accArry.count);
    [self.accTable reloadData];
}

- (void) accessoryBrowser:(HMAccessoryBrowser *)browser didRemoveNewAccessory:(nonnull HMAccessory *)accessory{
    NSLog(@"Remove deveice %@", accessory.name);
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark tableview

-(void)cofigureTableview
{

    self.accTable = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, self.view.bounds.size.height / 2,self.view.bounds.size.width,self.view.bounds.size.height / 2) style:UITableViewStylePlain];
    self.accTable.delegate = self;
    self.accTable.dataSource = self;
    [self.view addSubview:self.accTable];

}


- (NSInteger) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
        return _accArry.count;
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"cellIdentifier";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [self.accTable dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

    if(cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

    }
    HMAccessory *acc = _accArry[indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = acc.name;
    return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
{
    NSLog(@"title of cell %@", [self.accArry objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]);
    NSLog(@"current room: %@", self.currentRoom.name);
    NSLog(@"current home: %@", self.currentHome.name);

    HMAccessory *acc = _accArry[indexPath.row];
    __block HMHome *home = self.currentHome;
    __block HMRoom *room = self.currentRoom;



    [home addAccessory:acc completionHandler:^(NSError * _Nullable error) {
        if (error)
        {
            // Failed to add accessory to home
            NSLog(@"Fail to add device to home %@",error.localizedDescription);
        }
        else
        {
            if (acc.room != room) {
                // 3. If successfully, add the accessory to the room
                [home assignAccessory:acc toRoom:room completionHandler:^(NSError * _Nullable error) {
                    if (error) {
                        // Failed to add accessory to room
                        NSLog(@"Fail to assign room to room");
                    }
                    else{
                        NSLog(@"Add this device to %@", room.name);
                    }
                }];
            }
        }
    } ];


}
```

As you can see the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` function try to catch the two errors and `error.localizedDescription` only shows `Failed to add the accessory`

Why I cannot connect to the accessories? Where I did wrong? Thanks!!

Comment: Please show us the whole code file. There could be something other developers need to see to help you. Also, what have you done to troubleshoot your problem?

Comment: @moonman239 Thanks for reminding me. I have included the whole class that I deal with the accessories. I haven't done any troubleshooting because I don't know where I can start troubleshooting this......As I updated in the question, I remove two "catching error" conditions and let log show some error message.

Comment: I think I see where you're coming from. The accessory is there, otherwise Home wouldn't know what you're trying to connect to.

Comment: @moonman239 I am sorry I didn't get you......As you can see the first picture is the result after "discover". And then I select "Switch" to connect. Why the home doesn't know what I am trying to connect to??? :(

Comment: It does know what device you're trying to connect to. I was merely suggesting that because it knows what you're trying to connect to, we can rule out the possibililty that the accessory isn't in accArray.

Comment: @KathyLee where did you get this tutorial?

Comment: @MattyK14 Apple has its own guides for developers. https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/HomeKitDeveloperGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015050

Comment: @KathyLee Thanks, but I have already looked at it and haven't found it as helpful as I would have liked when it comes to setup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed by myself!!!!!!!!!!!

I made a mistake here. In function 
`- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated`

I should NOT include `[self.browser stopSearchingForNewAccessories]` , otherwise all the discover process will be stopped if I leave currentRoom page. So the correct version is

```
- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewWillDisappear:YES];
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.hidden = YES;
}
```

Stupid me but also genius!!!!! :)

Answer (score 0):

On the iPhone simulator, go to Settings->Privacy->HomeKit and select "Reset HomeKit Configuration".

If that doesn't work, delete Xcode and reinstall it from the App Store.

Comment: I tried what you said, deleted Xcode and reinstalled. Nothing changed..... And no "Reset Homekit Configuration" option in Homekit page.......